# How to play the audio again after completing the audio?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am facing the issue in playing the same audio after completing the audio. In my case i am using the play and pause function in a single button. When mediaplayer is playing the pause icon is visible ,when the audio is paused the play icon is visible.My problem is after audio is finished palying the audio, the mediaplayer seekbar should be in starting point of the audio and play button should be visible. How can i do this.

I tried `mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);`   but the after completing the audio it starts again but pause icon is visible and audio is playing continiously.

also i tried `

```
   mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      //     mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
            stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            seekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        }
    });
```

In this method it shows only the mediaplayer completing state.

My Requirement is after completing the audio the mediaplayer  should  be in initial state and in pause condition. If audio is pause means the play icon should be visible. [image]

In above image while playing the audio the pause image is visible, while in pause condition the play icon will be visible. When the audio is completed the seekbar position should be in starting point and audio should be pause condition.How to do this please help me.

Comment: the same example given [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) and its working fine no issue with that.You need to click on repeat song option for that it will automatically play the same song.

Comment: @  Andy Developer  i solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    //     mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
    //                stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //                seekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);

                    seekBar.setProgress(0);

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else {
                        stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I hope it's helpful to you ..!

Comment: The seekbar position is not changed , the seekbar position is in song end time

Comment: @ Sanjay Chauhan i will accept your you need to change the code

Comment: @  Sanjay Chauhan you should change this seekBar.setProgress(0);